# Pass binary file or byte[] from c# to java

Tags: c#, java, .net, arrays, multiplatform

I have a .net application in c# which receives a byte array and I need to send it to a Java Program as an argument, which is the best way to do it?

NOTE: Its all in the same server.

Comment: What does the byte array contain? Binary data or text?

Comment: Is the java app already running? or are you launching it?

Comment: How big is the array?

Comment: If you need to receive data of byte[] in your C# application, then you just write it as a file in the computer. If java app is running on same machine, use the java.io package with FileInputStream to handle the content.

Comment: The byteArray has a pdfFile, the java app has to be launched on request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start a Process and [redirect the input stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: While I'm in favor of this approach (barring further restrictions), it will prevent the C# program from continuing until the Java client entirely consumes and closes the input stream.

Comment: I like this approach, but does it work for binary data?
Sorry, I'll just use the input stream.. and can I return a stream from java?

Comment: For binary data just get the BaseStream from the TextWriter provided to you by the process, and use it as any stream.

Answer (score 0):

Send it over the [Looback address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback) (`127.0.0.1`) via sockets ([C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) & [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html)).  If it's just a simple `byte[]`, then this will be VERY simple on both ends.

With this, both the C# and Java applications can continue their process without interuption.