# Optimize way to pass a file for parsing in JAVA

Tags: java, android, file, file-io, binaryfiles

I am having two class getFile and readFile.
In getFile there is a method gettingFile() for getting the file, and a method parseFile() in readFile class which will parse the file.

```
public void gettting(){
    File file1= new File("abc.bin");
    ....
    ....
}
```

What I am confused about is, what would be the best way to send the "file1" to parseFile() method.
The three option that I have in my mind right now is: As a file itself..

```
parseFile(file1);
```

or as a byteArray..

```
DataInputStream dataIStream= new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file1));
BufferedInputStream bin= new BufferedInputStream(dataIStream);
byte[] byteArray= new byte[bin.available()];
bin.read(byteArray);
parseFile(byteArray);
```

or as an input stream..

```
parseFile(new FileInputStream(file1));
```

Or is it there any other better option than this?
The size of files I am going to parse is max: 20KB, min:1KB. All the files are **binary files** which have datas in a structured format. Right I am able to do it any of the above methods. I am thinking of which is the better one. 
**I am going to use this classes in an android application**
Here stackoverflow.com/a/21101403/2508414 it was saying about as an inputstream. Or is my understanding wrong.

Comment: What do you consider to be the simplest?  Without more information, there is no definitive "best" way.

Comment: Note that your array variant won't necessarily process the whole file

Comment: @PeterLawrey the size of files I am going to parse is max: 20KB, min:1KB. All the files are binary files. I have to parse it and get the necessary information

Comment: @kaze So the size is unlikely to matter and I would use what you feel is the simplest approach.

Answer (score 2):

You have following options:

- **Pass the File**
  This means you can only process files. I wouldn't use this, unless you need the meta data (name, size, ...). Also, the file passed could be a directory, meaning additional checks.
- **Pass the data as byte array**
  This requires a lot of effort to read the data first, and also doesn't scale well with larger data (all of it would have to be in the memory). Not recommended.
- **Pass an URL**
  This is more flexible as the file variant, as it allows to pass file URLs (file.toURI().toURL()), resource URLs (Class.getResource(...)) and web URLs. The data is then read by opening an input stream from the URL. Recommended for any resources.
- **Pass the data as InputStream**
  Very flexible, the input stream can be created from anything (also useful for testing, allows to create the test data from a String). Also efficient, allows streaming of data. Generally recommended. Hint: always wrap the passed `InputStream` into a `BufferedInputStream`, this greatly improves performance.
- **Pass the data as a Reader**
  When reading character data, this is the recommended alternative to using an InputStream (where you would need to know the character encoding, or would need to pass it as an additional argument). Hint: always wrap the passed `Reader` into a `BufferedReader`, this greatly improves performance.

If you write a reusable API, I recommend to provide following variants:

```
void parseFile(URL url) // delegate to parseFile(Reader)
void parseFile(InputStream in, String encoding) // delegate to parseFile(Reader)
void parseFile(Reader reader) // parsing code
```

Comment: So for binary files, the best way is to pass it as an Inputstream wrapped in BufferedIS? As I have to parse the necessary datas by the data structure format (int, char,etc) which is provided to me.

Comment: If it contains character data which is to be parsed, passing it as Reader is recommended (allows to read the data as chars, instead of bytes). The BufferedReader also allows to read the data line-by-line, which might be helpful when reading data with line breaks.

Comment: I am not reading text files, the datas in the binary file "abc.bin" which I am reading are encoded in such a way that the first 2 byte will represent an integer value, the next 5 bytes will be the name of the file, the value of next single byte will represent the number of certain object and so on..

Comment: If I pass it as an inputstream inside gettingFile method like **parseFile(bin);** and catch it as **parseFile(BufferedInputStream bis)** where do I need to close the stream? In **parseFile()** method or **gettingFile()** method or both?

Comment: When reading from streams/readers until it is exhausted (no more data available), it's a good idea to close it right away. This is optional, as the party that opens the stream is also responsible for closing it. I'd use try-with-resources (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think the normal way is you pass the File object through and have 1 method creating and closing the streams.

The File object is nothing but consider it a file descriptor which doesn't have any resources associated. Once you open the stream for a file, then there is the problem about who is responsible to close it. Normally we could follow "who create the resource is in charge of destroying it" that means the file stream opening and closing should really be in the same method.

If you want to customize the parsing of the content, you should make the line parsing method abstract (given you talking about parsing I assume this is plain text file) or subclass that part.

Having said all the above, if you are indeed doing text parsing, you should use BufferedReader which has both a lot of convenient methods like readLine() as well as better performance since it keeps a buffer internally, instead of going to the stream each time for a character.

Comment: I have edited my question, have a look. So, I have decided to pass it as a buffered input stream inside gettingFile method like **parseFile(bin);** and catch it as **parseFile(BufferedInputStream bis)** where do I need to close these stream? In **parseFile()** method or **gettingFile()** method or both?

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the file and let the parsing method read it as it needs to. Preloading it into a byte array just wastes time and space.

Comment: I have edited my question, is passing as a file object the best option still?

Comment: Here http://stackoverflow.com/a/21101403/2508414 it was saying about as an inputstream. Or is my understanding wrong.

Comment: Pass the `File` or an `InputStream`, whichever suits you best, or both, and forget about the `byte[]` option.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is that there are **two** ways to think about this:

- inputting the File directly just saves time and is simple to understand
- providing a byte array as input allows more flexibility as to where the content comes from, as long as it is eventually transformed into a byte array, you could eventually have an external service that feeds the content from somewhere else

I would go for the **second** option, and as a suggestion give the [Apache Commons IO](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io/2.4) library a try. It has a FileUtils and IOUtils class that provides some convenient methods for playing around with files and streams.